# Do I need a personal apple developer account to publish apps that is separate from my company account?

Tags: ios, account

I have been working for an organization for some time and my Apple Developer account is tied to that company. If I would like to publish an app on my own, would I need to pay the $99 for another personal account?

Side note: When assigning a team on Xcode I noticed that it has my company name and an option that says "My Name (Personal Account - myemail@email.com). Is this a personal account that I can publish through? It is still the same account tied to the organization.

Comment: Do **NOT** publish your own **personal** apps using your Company's account (unless you own the company).. should go without saying :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay another $99 for a separate account to publish under. You could link your same email to that account, then iTunes Connect would give you a team option when you sign in